# Errors deploying app on Heroku: not running start script properly and get requests failing

Tags: node.js, npm, heroku

I'm trying to deploy my app on Heroku but I keep receiving this error. I'm not sure how I can resolve this problem in my own source code. I think the start error might be because in my scripts I have two start options:
"start:backend": "nodemon backend.js",
"start:frontend": "react-scripts start",.

How can I resolve this problem? I'm also not sure what is going wrong with the paths and get requests.

````
2022-08-03T23:37:55.245406+00:00 heroku[router]: at=error code=H10 desc="App crashed" method=GET path="/" host=calm-stream-00694.herokuapp.com request_id=f48450ec-3ead-40fb-8ccc-f25532f1fe0a fwd="99.225.37.41" dyno= connect= service= status=503 bytes= protocol=https
2022-08-03T23:37:55.445318+00:00 heroku[router]: at=error code=H10 desc="App crashed" method=GET path="/favicon.ico" host=calm-stream-00694.herokuapp.com request_id=b90566e5-a089-45ad-95bb-a91da389f92c fwd="99.225.37.41" dyno= connect= service= status=503 bytes= protocol=https
2022-08-03T23:39:13.971134+00:00 heroku[web.1]: State changed from crashed to starting
2022-08-03T23:39:26.279431+00:00 heroku[web.1]: Starting process with command `npm run start`
2022-08-03T23:39:27.778014+00:00 heroku[web.1]: Process exited with status 1
2022-08-03T23:39:27.861645+00:00 heroku[web.1]: State changed from starting to crashed
2022-08-03T23:39:27.872168+00:00 heroku[web.1]: State changed from crashed to starting
2022-08-03T23:39:27.617450+00:00 app[web.1]: npm WARN config production Use `--omit=dev` instead.
2022-08-03T23:39:27.634032+00:00 app[web.1]: npm ERR! Missing script: "start"
2022-08-03T23:39:27.634167+00:00 app[web.1]: npm ERR!
2022-08-03T23:39:27.634286+00:00 app[web.1]: npm ERR! Did you mean one of these?
2022-08-03T23:39:27.634412+00:00 app[web.1]: npm ERR!     npm star # Mark your favorite packages
2022-08-03T23:39:27.634452+00:00 app[web.1]: npm ERR!     npm stars # View packages marked as favorites
2022-08-03T23:39:27.634492+00:00 app[web.1]: npm ERR!
2022-08-03T23:39:27.634598+00:00 app[web.1]: npm ERR! To see a list of scripts, run:
2022-08-03T23:39:27.634599+00:00 app[web.1]: npm ERR!   npm run
2022-08-03T23:39:27.636041+00:00 app[web.1]:
2022-08-03T23:39:27.636210+00:00 app[web.1]: npm ERR! A complete log of this run can be found in:
2022-08-03T23:39:27.636264+00:00 app[web.1]: npm ERR!     /app/.npm/_logs/2022-08-03T23_39_27_592Z-debug-0.log
2022-08-03T23:39:40.250299+00:00 heroku[web.1]: Starting process with command `npm run start`
2022-08-03T23:39:41.591800+00:00 heroku[web.1]: Process exited with status 1
2022-08-03T23:39:41.660469+00:00 heroku[web.1]: State changed from starting to crashed```
````

Comment: what did you do to setup your app to be deployed on Heroku?

Comment: @Dan I followed along with this tutorial https://betterprogramming.pub/deploy-your-app-for-free-in-7-easy-steps-thanks-to-heroku-dfd0f387edd0

Answer (score 0):

Heroku runs `start` script from your package.json. If you have multiple start scripts (`start:backend`, `start:frontend`...), you should specify which script to run (in your case I guess backend):

```
{
    "scripts": {
      "start": "npm run start:backend"
    }
}
```

By the way heroku can't run multiple scripts, so your backend should automatically serve frontend! Build frontend and serve it with backend.

Comment: yes, if you don't specify `.procfile` and which commands shall be run, `heroku` by default tries to find&run `start` script from your `package.json`. If there is no such script, error like yours will be shown. Add `start` script in your `package.json` push it and redeploy. `"start": "node backend.js"`